# PubSub cloud function to write to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Pub/Sub topic that my Raspberry Pi's will publish their sensor data to.  This cloud function logs the published data:

**main.py**

```
import sys

def log_sensor_data(event, context):
    import base64

    if 'data' in event:
        message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')

        # if 'sensor data ready' in message:          # check which message is listed
        #     print('lets store the data in firebase...')

    if 'attributes' in event:                           # NOTE: the key of 'attributes' is plural even though Pub/Sub uses the command line "--attribute" (singular)
        sensorName = 'unknown sensor'                   # default values
        temperature = -1
        humidity = -1

        if 'sensorName' in event['attributes']:
            sensorName = event['attributes']['sensorName']
        
        if 'temperature' in event['attributes']:
            temperature = event['attributes']['temperature']
        
        if 'humidity' in event['attributes']:
            humidity = event['attributes']['humidity']
    
        print(f'sensor name: {sensorName}')
        print(f'temperature: {temperature}')
        print(f'humidity: {humidity}')
```

But when I try to add code to write the data to a Firestore database, I'm having no luck.

Just adding `from google.cloud import firestore` gives the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'firestore' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)`.

Is the only option for writing cloud functions for Firestore using this guide, https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions ? I'd really like to keep using Python.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write a Cloud Function in Python to interact with PubSub and Cloud Firestore, create a folder with 2 files named `main.py` and `requirements.txt`.

**main.py**

```
from google.cloud import firestore

client = firestore.Client(project='My_PROJECT_ID')

def hello_fire(event, context):
    import base64

    print(f'This function was triggered by messageId {context.event_id}, published at {context.timestamp} to {context.resource["name"]}!')

    # google's hello world log example
    if 'data' in event:
        name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    else:
        name = 'World'
    print(f'Hello {name}!')
    
    # write to a new doc in Firestore
    doc = client.collection('MY_FIRESTORE_COLLECTION').document('NEW_UNIQUE_DOC_NAME')
    doc.set({
        'first': 'Ada',
        'last': 'Lovelace',
        'born': 1815
    })
```

**requirements.txt**

```
google-cloud-firestore>=2.1.3
```

When setting up the `client` variable, you can get a list of all of your Google Cloud project IDs with the following terminal command: `gcloud projects list`

To deploy the function, open a terminal and `cd` to your folder, then type:

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_fire --runtime python39 --trigger-topic MY_PUBSUB_TOPIC
```

Note that when you deploy, you'll use the short name of your topic (ex: 'garden-sensors'), not the long form name (ex: 'projects/MY_PROJECT_ID/topics/garden-sensors').

Make sure you've enabled Cloud Firestore in your project as well as having set up a PubSub topic.

Thank you @Ranveer and @al-dann for helping me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put data like this.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

# Use a service account
cred = credentials.Certificate('<key>.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

doc_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(u'alovelace')
doc_ref.set({
    u'first': u'Ada',
    u'last': u'Lovelace',
    u'born': 1815
})
```

Comment: Hi Ranveer, this gives the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin'`

Comment: You need first install firebase_admin dependency in your system. pip install firebase_admin

Answer (score 0):

I would divide the problem into 3 parts.

The **first** part - to be sure that the Firestore and API is up and running in a proper project.

The **second** part - the service account under which the cloud function is executed - should have relevant IAM roles to work with the Firestore. See -  [Predefined Firestore IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam#predefined_roles) Three things to check here:

- project id - the firestore and the cloud function might be in different projects
- IAM role - for example - `roles/datastore.user`
- service account of the cloud function

The **third** part - the cloud function code.

API description: [Python Client for Google Cloud Firestore](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/index.html)

At first - the correct import in the `requirements.txt` - for example `google-cloud-firestore>=2.0.2`

Then, a few code elements.

1/ Import:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
```

2/ Firestore Client creation outside of the function body, so it is created once when a new instance of the cloud function is loaded/created in the memory:

```
DB = firestore.Client(project=<the project id where the firestore is located>)
```

3/ Function code (inside the function body) - just a snippet example to start with:

```
...
fs_file_ref = DB.document(<collection name>/<document id>) 
...
```

Bear in mind, that depending on API versions, the function signatures might be different from the examples I provided.